# lookupReference in ViewController is not working

Tags: viewcontroller, extjs5

I have created a view like this

```
Ext.define('Project.view.Test', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',

    controller: 'testController',

    requires: [
        'Ext.button.Button',
    ],

    trackResetOnLoad: true,
    items: [{
        xype: 'button',
        text: 'testbutton',
        reference: 'testbutton',
        itemId: 'testbutton'
    }]
});
```

this.lookupReference('testbutton')  in init() of ViewController is returning null.
But this.getView().getComponent('testbutton') is returning the button.

What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: I would recommend using lookupReference from the 'afterrender' view controller event instead of init()

Comment: I had to set referenceHolder: true explicitly to make this work .